# How do I ask for a users name and display it thrice using the for loop?

Tags: python

So i'm pretty new to coding, i learnt about strings, if statements etc, in school. Next week we're learning **for loops** but i want to get a heads up on it. So the teacher told me to  "Display a users name thrice using the for loop"
Here's what i think:

```
name = input("What is your name?!")
for x in range(name):
print(name)
```

Please help me fix this, with an explanation of how the code was processed! Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `range(name)` means?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you follow some good tutorial rather than try to learn by more or less random trial and error, you would spare much time and effort,

Comment: @ScottHunter if i had a variable called name and a integer-variable called number then id ask it to enter its name and enter its number. What itd do then is post that number with the amount of time you had posted a number, quick example i just did:

nom1 = input("Enter your name again " )
data = int(input("Ok Enter a number now " ))
for x in range(data):
    print(nom1)

*As a scenario**

Comment: I think your question is if you input incorrect answer then it will ask again and if you pur correct then it will access like mobile passcode to get 3 time password to input correct password otherwise it will lock you phone for 1 minute like this right? because if you you for loop then it will print same thing 3 time only but you need I think countdown type

Comment: @ThierryLathuille do you mind providing some?

Comment: You can find a list at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: I personnally enjoyed doing my first steps with https://automatetheboringstuff.com/ which is a free resource (also available as a book) and a very good place to start. I second Thierry Lathuille, this will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple...

First, the version you gave tries to *iterate* (loop over) the string which is the name variable.

This is not possible. If you want to print it thrice, iterate for 3 times (`range(3)`).
The final code is here.

###### Final note: remember indentation, it shows it is part of the loop.

```py
name = input("What's your name: ") # Same as before
for i in range(3):                 # Iterate 3 times
    print(name)                    # Display name, note: indented
```

Comment: "...with an explanation of how the code was processed"

Comment: thanks,quick question though. How is it you can use for **i** in range and for **x** in range?

Comment: added explanation

Comment: They both work. It essentially just assigns `x` or `i` to 0 on the first loop, 1 on the second and 2 on the third. The name of x or i does not matter. For all Python cares, you could use `thisIsAVariableName` or something ridiculous.

Comment: That was to @Lumiscnt1

Comment: An extra note, in this scenario, I'd change `i` to `_`, since we are not printing out i or doing anything with the value `i`. (It's just a convention, a standard way of doing it - if you don't use the variable, use an underscore rather than a name such as `i`).

Answer (score 0):

Close: You need to iterate through the for loop three times.

So, we'll use `range(3)` to do so. The loop will run `print(name)` three times because of `range(3)`, resulting in the name being printed thrice. If you'd like to print it five times, you'd change it to `range(5)`.

```
name = input("What is your name?!")
for x in range(3):
    print(name)
```

You should learn about how the `range` function works because your code uses `range(name)`, which has no meaning.

When you input a single integer `n` into `range`, it's interpreted as the numeric series starting from `0` and ending at `n-1`. So `range(3)` corresponds to the series `(0,1,2)`. Notice that it has three entries - thus, `name` will be printed three times.

Comment: I see, thanks! So if i understand, what the code practically does is iterates in-to the loop thrice. Therefore **range(3)** is used. Thanks again!